# Links ending with .docx or .pdf

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There are some links ending .docs/ .pdf/ .txt
and I want to click the one ending .docx.
How can i write an Xpath? or is there any other way selecting links ending with some text?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '.docx')]")).click();
```

Which would match any link that contains the string `.docx` in its `href` attribute. Or, if you want to be more specific:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 4) = '.docx']")).click();
```

Which would match only links where the `href` attribute ends with `.docx`.